# Passing laravel root folder on other pc

Tags: php, laravel

I had worked with our website made with laravel 4.1 and it needs to be passed to my groupmates to add their work. the webpage works well on my browser, after passing on my classmate's pc, the homepage load but other routes are not working.

How to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like some kind of htaccess error. Does your public directory contain a .htaccess file? What errors are you getting?

Comment: `but other routes are not working` doesn't tells anything.

Comment: Yes ptimson, it has an .htaccess file. 
it says that there is no directory found then the url address. basically the routes are not working

Comment: I already fix the problem with the help of others. check only the rewrite_module on apache.